# Wine cannot simulate a system reboot after Microsoft Office configuration

Tags: software-installation, wine, microsoft-word

I managed to install Microsoft's [Office 2010](https://www.ecosia.org/google?q=blogspot%202013%20microsoft-office-professional-plus-2010) (32 bit) with [WINE](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) in Linux Mint 18 (Xfce, 32-bit) on an ASUS eeePC.

So I tried to open freshly installed MS Office Word in Wine. It tried to configure something, followed by a necessary reboot. So I clicked to "restart system". The results was Wine's error message:

> a simulated log-off or shutdown is in progress but this program isn't responding if you terminate the process you may lose all unsaved data

Comment: What happens after you close Word (and any other apps running in wine) and run it again?

Comment: Any unsaved data seem to be lost, because Word keeps trying to configure anew. And it produces a huge log file, should I publish it?

Comment: Does running `wineboot` help at all?

Comment: I gave up trying with wine. Now it works fine in VirtualBox